# Remove shadow from UIBarButtonItem Image

Tags: ios5, uibarbuttonitem, shadow

[image: UIBarButtonItem]

Is there an easy way to remove the stupid image shadow from a uibarbuttonitem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the only way is to put an UIButton within an UIBarButton. So there is no way to directly remove the shadow from an uibarbutton image.